# Display html table from date wrapper

Tags: html

I have a List that gets populated based on Start Date and end Date range that user has provided on UI.
Say for example, if Start Date = 01/02/2017 and End Date = 15/02/2017, than List of dateWrapper will contain 15 entires as per the date range.

Now I want to create an html table where static header will be week days i.e. 1 row (one tr)  with 7 columns (7 td's) (Sunday to Saturday).
Than the dynamically iterating over list, table rows and columns needs to be placed as the date range.

As an output, the table should look like:

```
Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
                 1   2   3
 4   5   7   8   9  10  11
12  13  14  15
```

How do we achieve this?

Approach that I tried is below:

    
    
        
        
        
            Sunday
        
        
            Monday
        
        
            Tuesday
        
        
            Wednesday
        
        
            Thursday
        
        
            Friday
        
        
            Saturday

```
<!-- Dynamically display table data below-->
    <apex:repeat var="datewrap" value="{!dateWrapperList}">
    <tr>
      <td data-label="Sunday">
        <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!if(datewrap.dayOfWeek = 'Sun', true, false)}">
               <b>{!dateWrap.dateValue}</b>
            </apex:outputPanel>
      </td>
      <td data-label="Monday">
        <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!if(dateWrap.dayOfWeek = 'Mon', true, false)}">
               <b>{!dateWrap.dateValue}</b>
            </apex:outputPanel>
      </td>
      <td data-label="Tuesday">
        <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!if(dateWrap.dayOfWeek = 'Tue', true, false)}">
               <b>{!dateWrap.dateValue}</b>
            </apex:outputPanel>
      </td>
      <td data-label="Wednesday">
        <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!if(dateWrap.dayOfWeek = 'Wed', true, false)}">
               <b>{!dateWrap.dateValue}</b>
            </apex:outputPanel>
      </td>
      <td data-label="Thursday">
        <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!if(dateWrap.dayOfWeek = 'Thu', true, false)}">
               <b>{!dateWrap.dateValue}</b>
            </apex:outputPanel>
      </td>
      <td data-label="Friday">
        <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!if(dateWrap.dayOfWeek = 'Fri', true, false)}">
               <b>{!dateWrap.dateValue}</b>
            </apex:outputPanel>
      </td>
      <td data-label="Saturday">
        <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!if(dateWrap.dayOfWeek = 'Sat', true, false)}">
               <b>{!dateWrap.dateValue}</b>
            </apex:outputPanel>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </apex:repeat>
</table>
```

Incorrect Output:

```
Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
                 1   
                     2   
                         3
 4   
     5   
         6
            7   
                8   
                    9  
                        10  
11
    12  
        13  
            14  
                15
```

Expected Output:
    Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
                     1   2   3
     4   5   7   8   9  10  11
    12  13  14  15

Comment: please edit your post to include what you have tried so far, and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's at least two basic ways to do this.

My preference is to have a higher-level wrapper, a WeekWrapper, to show the data. That makes the markup look like this:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!weeks}" var="week">
  <tr>
    <apex:repeat value="{!week.days}" var="day">
      <td> ... </td>
    </apex:repeat>
  </tr>
</apex:repeat>
```

If you want to just keep it as a list of days, consider using CSS instead:

```
<apex:page controller="CalendarExample">
    <style>
        .col7 {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 14%;
        }
    </style>
    <div>
        <span class="col7">Sunday   </span>
        <span class="col7">Monday   </span>
        <span class="col7">Tuesday  </span>
        <span class="col7">Wednesday</span>
        <span class="col7">Thursday </span>
        <span class="col7">Friday   </span>
        <span class="col7">Saturday </span>
        <apex:repeat value="{!month}" var="day">
            <span class="col7">{!day(day.dateValue)}</span>
        </apex:repeat>
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

---

```
public class CalendarExample {
    public class DateWrapper {
        public Date dateValue { get; set; }
        public DateWrapper(Date value) {
            dateValue = value;
        }
    }
    public DateWrapper[] month { get; set; }
    public CalendarExample() {
        Date startDate = Date.today().toStartOfMonth().toStartOfWeek(),
            endDate = Date.today().addMonths(1).toStartOfMonth().toStartOfWeek().addDays(7),
            dateIndex = startDate;
        Integer currentMonth = Date.today().month();
        month = new DateWrapper[0];
        while(dateIndex < endDate) {
            if(dateIndex.month() == currentMonth) {
                month.add(new DateWrapper(dateIndex.addDays(0)));
            } else {
                month.add(new DateWrapper(null));
            }
            dateIndex = dateIndex.addDays(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in all of these solutions, you still want to have the blank day as cells (e.g. Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, and Wednesday on the first week in your example would be empty values).

Comment: The tricky part is to display blank cells for Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed using date wrapper. I tried the rendered attribute approach as shown in my code, but it displayed table in unexpected manner.

Comment: @Shrey Yes, as I said, you'd have extra array elements for Sun-Wed, as in your example, placed at the beginning of the list.

Comment: @Shrey And, you're rendering one `tr` per day, which is why it's 15 rows tall. Splitting the data into a WeekWrapper would make it easier to visualize, I think, and it's the way I wrote it as a novice. These days, I'd skip using a table at all and simply use a series of properly sized inline-block CSS elements.

Comment: @sfdcox so is it correct if I state that my expected output is not possible using this panelgrid approach: <apex:panelGrid columns="7">
  <apex:repeat value="{!days}" var="day">
    <apex:panel>
      {!day.number}
    </apex:panel>
  </apex:repeat>
</apex:panelGrid> and I will have to use week wrapper to display the table in calendar fashion

Comment: @Shrey If you use the panelGrid, it should render your rows correctly for you. It's been a while since I've used it, but I think I could dredge up some old source code.

Comment: @Shrey I wrote up a pure CSS example to show you how I added padding to the start of the week. This will copy-paste into your org so you can play around with it.

Comment: thank you for your quick response. I will try out this solution :)

Comment: I applied weekwrapper approach as it was more clean and easy to visualize and maintain. It was bit tricky to handle this wrapper but was able to manage it.